# Conditionally compare value of array and set it to a variable

Tags: javascript, arrays, if-statement, ecmascript-6

So I am trying to set a flag emoji to the `flag` variable depending on the value of the passed `dishes` array of objects.
I have a solution, but I bet this can be improved. I mean just imagine 50 countries ...

```
let flag = ''
const countryFlags = ['', '', '', '']
const dishes = [
   { dish: 'pizza', origin: 'italian' },
   { dish: 'tzatziki', origin: 'greek' }
]

const chooseFlag = a => {
    if (a === 'german') flag = countryFlags[0]
    if (a === 'greek') flag = countryFlags[1]
    if (a === 'spanish') flag = countryFlags[2]
    if (a === 'italian') flag = countryFlags[3]
}

chooseFlag(dishes.origin)
```

Anybody got a shorthand solution?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can create a `map` of key-value pairs (`key` being the country and `value` being the code):

```js
let flag = ''
const countryToFlags = {
  'german':'', 
  'greek':'', 
  'spanish':'',
  'italian':''
}
const dishes = [
   { dish: 'pizza', origin: 'italian' },
   { dish: 'tzatziki', origin: 'greek' }
]

const chooseFlag = a => {
    flag = countryToFlags[a];
}

chooseFlag(dishes[0].origin);

console.log(flag);
```

Comment: Okey maybe I should've clarified that the values I am conditionally setting are actually values of an external array of objects: [{dish:pizza, origin:italian }, {dish:tzatziki, origin:greek}] etc. And now I need to compare the value of the ```key``` 'origin' to this flagArray and return the given emoji

Comment: Other than adding a couple of checks (such as `return countryToFlags[a.toLowerCase()]` and maybe adding a default blank 'unknown' flag for those times where something goes wrong, there aren't all that many further options.

Comment: @andy: remember that *we know nothing at all about your code, except what you tell us.* With that in mind, consider editing your question to add as much context as you feel is relevant and enough of your code that we can reproduce your problem.

Comment: @andylib93 I think it's similar. I updated the answer to set the ``flag`` instead. You need to specify what ``dish`` element you want to pass the function. You can use the ``countryFlags`` array as the values in the map instead of strings if you want.